# Android - How is Canvas Used

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm trying to draw circles using SurfaceView and I was curious about whether or not you always use canvas when you draw something. Are there are other ways instead of using canvas, and what are the pros/cons? Also, how would you personally draw a circle with SurfaceView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no other ways to draw instead of canvas.
You can use SurfaceView to draw any shape even a cricle also.
First you ahev to get SurfaceHolder object and using that you can draw anything.
Yo can follow these links- [first](http://android-coding.blogspot.jp/2011/05/drawing-on-surfaceview.html) [second](http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-draw-graphics-in-android)

Comment: I want to add more information. Surface\view is a powerful version of simple View. If you want to build powerful custom views SurfaceView is more powerful. It is almost similar to OpenGls GlSurfaceView.

Comment: @サラマラージ SurfaceView is very different from a custom View (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), most notably in that the Surface is a completely separate layer. You can use OpenGL ES with a plain SurfaceView -- GLSurfaceView can be handy but is not required.

Comment: But you can use SurfaceView to create a Custom View. I have created a game using this technique.

Comment: Creating a custom View (as in the link I included above) using a SurfaceView is a waste of resources. If you're going to draw on the View, having the unused Surface sitting around doesn't make sense -- just subclass a plain View. If you're going to use the SurfaceView Surface, it rarely makes sense to draw on the View unless you want an overlay or mask effect, so subclassing is frowned upon ("prefer composition over inheritance").

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic options: use a Canvas, or OpenGL ES.

The easiest way to draw a circle is to use [`Canvas#drawCircle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)).  Doing the equivalent with OpenGL ES is more involved, though there are various toolkits that can simplify things.

Depending on your needs, you may want to consider using a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) instead.  Canvas rendering on a SurfaceView is not hardware accelerated, but Canvas rendering on a custom View can be.